# Openthread MAC Address vs EUI64

Tags: openthread

In openthread project :https://github.com/openthread/openthread
Can someone explain to me the deference between MAC Address, eui64, hardware address and extended address?
Why there are so many different types of unique ids?

I looked in to the source code and it looks like the EUI64 is take from the chip read only registers
and the extended address is randomly generated but then when i scan for devices on the area under HwAddr i see the generated extended address, but it doesn't make sense.

please help me to make some sense in to it.

Answer (score 0):

While IEEE EUI-64 is intended to support a globally unique identifier, in practice, a randomly generated 64-bit value is much less likely to have collisions. This is often due to mistakes in managing IEEE EUI-64 assignment.

MAC Address typically refers to the L2 address. However, IEEE 802.15.4 has two types of L2 addresses - Short (16-bit) and Extended (64-bit).